# How to check/test value of a UISwitch using KIF?

Tags: ios, uiswitch, kif

I've been able to find the following KIF method for setting the value of a `UISwitch`:

```
tester.setOn(false, forSwitchWithAccessibilityLabel: "Enable Feature")
```

However, I have been unable to figure out how to retrieve the value of a UISwitch, using KIF, in an assert/test approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

To test for switch on:

```
tester.waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Enable Feature", value: "1", traits: UIAccessibilityTraitNone)
```

To test for switch off:

```
tester.waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Enable Feature", value: "0", traits: UIAccessibilityTraitNone)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel` returns a view. So how about this?

```
let view = tester().waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel("Enable Feature")
let switchView = view as? UISwitch
XCTAssertNotNil(switchView)
XCTAssertTrue(switchView!.on) // or XCTAssertFalse(switchView!.on)
```